# jupyter python notebook using elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, data-science-experience

I am using elasticsearch with jupyter python notebook in DSX. When I write a dataframe to objectstorage, I get an error:

> ratings_df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").save("swift://DSConnections.spark/ratings.es")
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o96.save.
> : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install elasticsearch connector.

`import pixiedust
pixiedust.installPackage("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.4.4")`

Reference for PixiedustManager

http://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/Package-Manager.html#installfrommavensearch

Thanks,
Charles.